# Unable to download firmware updates?

Tags: firmware

I am new to Linux, I keep getting this error message. How do I fix this. Dual booting win10 and Ubuntu 18.10:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a terminal try

```
sudo fwupdmgr refresh
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

Answer (score 0):

You could update your firmware using the `fwudp` command.

Open the terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and
update your system first -> `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

Now use following commands one by one:

```
sudo service fwupd start
sudo fwupdmgr refresh
sudo fwupdmgr update
```